# how to disable overlay in jqModal popup

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

I am doing with [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#examples) plugin. I need to disable the outer overlay and make the popup stable. So that, until "close" button is clicked, the popup should be showing  consistently.

Code so far I tried (the commented options are unable to produce the expected effect) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dialog').jqm(
        /* {
        overlay : 100%,
        modal : false
        }*/
    );
});​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3J5wW/1/

Comment: well documentation says you have to do `overlay: 0` to disable it

Comment: but at the same time it is making the background transparent. I need a semi-transparent/solid background

Comment: so you are looking for this? http://jsfiddle.net/armababy/3J5wW/3/

Comment: @arma yes exactly that's what I need. Thank you very much, I could accept if you put this into answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following from comments to close this thread.
To disable overlays modal exit event jqModal has to have 2 settings:

```
overlay : 50, // Overlay opacity value 1-100, 0 will disable overlay all together
modal   : true
```

Full example [at fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/armababy/3J5wW/3/)